# Parallel Vectors

Tags: vectors

Found this on a textbook and I know I am missing out something really simple as it's been a while for me with vectors so here it goes:If $ \Bbb P=mi-2j+2k$  (where i,j,k are unit vectors) and $ \Bbb Q=2i-nj+k $ are parallel to each other, then find $m$ and $n$

Comment: $i,j,k$ linearly independant? $p$ and $q$ are parallel if they are colinear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a scalar $a$ such that $p = aq$, which yields the equations $m = 2a$, $-2 = -na$ and $2 = a$. By plugging the last equation into the first two this gives us $m = 4$ and $n = 1$.